# What's best/correct English? (something) isn't consistently in place, OR (something) is inconsistently in place?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, adverb-position

(something) isn't consistently in place, OR (something) is inconsistently in place?

Comment: er...not always in place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(something) isn't consistently in place, OR (something) is inconsistently in place?*

I would say they are both awkward but that they also both mean different things.

Something that isn't consistently in place is binary and not always there or in place while something that is inconsistently in place is erratic which has the connotation of being more chaotic.

I would offer "The penny jar is not always on the window sill" or, in a more formal or business manner "The delivery of the servers is inconsistent".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest both options are good. It's up to you how you want to use it.
Sometimes we need to avoid "not" or negative words so you could use later in that case.

Answer (score 0):

They are both grammatically correct statements, but they are focusing on something different. By saying that something "*isn't consistently in place*" (which you can reword as "is consistently out of place" if you want to avoid the negative), you are focusing on the fault. It comes across as a criticism. On the other hand, by saying that something is "*inconsistently in place*" you are focusing on the positive. If we were talking about an employee being on time, for example: 
**He is consistently late** focuses on his tardiness and is communicating his unreliability. 
**He is inconsistently on time**, on the other hand, is saying that yeah, he's on time! Just not always.

So the question is what you want to focus on. What feeling do you want the statement to communicate, disappointment, or begrudging acceptance?